# jQuery Click function doesn't work on Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, click

I want to put menu's style switcher on my site but it doesn't work on Chrome / IE / Safari (works well on FireFox). Here's some code:

```
    // Menu Style Switcher
    $("#option-1").click(function(){
        $("#navigation").removeClass("style-2");
    });

    $("#option-2").click(function(){
        $("#navigation").addClass("style-2");
    });


<div class="menu-style">
    <select>
        <option id="option-1">Style 1</option>
        <option id="option-2">Style 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should listen to the the [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event on the whole `<select>` element.

**Markup**:

```
<select id="yourSelect">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

**JS**:

```
$('#yourSelect').change(function(e){

    if( $(this).val() == 1){

        $("#navigation").removeClass("style-2");        

    }else{

        $("#navigation").addClass("style-2");        

    }
}
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ACW27/).

Comment: @DumbProducts you aren't referring to the select element.

Answer (score 5):

The `addClassName` does not exist. The correct name of the function is `addClass`

---

The other improvement would be to use the `change` event of the `select` element instead of the `click` on the options..

```
// Menu Style Switcher
$('.menu-style select').change(function(){
    if (this.value === 'Style 1'){
        $("#navigation").removeClass("style-2");
    } else {
        $("#navigation").addClass("style-2");
    }
});
```